# Apache Storm Installation without ZeroMQ/JZMQ

Tags: apache-storm

I am trying to setup a multi-cluster storm system. I have found several 3rd party step by step guides on this. They all have Java, Python, ZeroMQ 2.1.7 and JZMQ as the requirements for the Nimbus and Supervisor/Slave nodes. But on the official Apache Storm website, the only requirements for the Nimbus and Supervisor nodes is Java 6 and Python 2.6.6 (https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html)

Does anyone know if ZeroMQ and JZMQ are required for Storm cluster configuration? And is there an advantage to have these two softwares installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Storm 0.9.0 and onwards, 0MQ should no longer be needed and you can use Netty instead but it needs to be configured. Please see http://storm.apache.org/2013/12/08/storm090-released.html for quick config setup.