# How to configure zookeeper, kafka and storm in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I want to clear steps of how to install zookeeper, kafka and storm in Ubuntu

Comment: What do you think this is? A server buffet?

Comment: I felt it's helpful as I faced many problems while installing so.@JonathonReinhart

Comment: Newer versions of Storm use Netty instead of ZeroMQ according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145475/apache-storm-installation-without-zeromq-jzmq which was answered in 2015.

Answer (score 2):

It will guide through sequence of steps :

Kafka binary file already has built-in Zookeeper with it, so you don't need to download it separately. Download Kafka at the below link.

```
Download Kafka version 0.8.2.0 from http://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html
```

Release and Un-tar the zip file using the below commands

**tar -xzf kafka_2.9.1-0.8.2.0.tgz**

Go into the extracted folder

**cd kafka_2.9.1-0.8.2.0**

Start the Zookeeper Server(which listens on port 2181 for kafka server requests)

**bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties**

Now start the Kafka Server in a new terminal window

**bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties**

Now let us test if the zookeeper-kafka configuration is working.
Open a new terminal and Create a topic test:

**bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test**

**bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181**

Use a producer to Kafka's topic test:

**bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test**
This is a message(You have to enter these messages)
This is another message

Use Kafka's Consumer to see the messages produced :

**bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning**

The above command should list all the messages you typed earlier. That's it. You successfully configured your Zookeeper-Kafka Single Broker.

To configure multil-broker use the link following, refer the official site kafka.apache.org

Now Let's install Apache Storm :

Download tar.gz file from mirrorShttp://mirrors.ibiblio.org/apache/storm/apache-storm-0.9.2-incubating/

Extract it : **$tar xzvf apache-storm-0.9.2-incubating.tar.gz**

Create a data directory

**sudo mkdir /var/stormtmp**

**sudo chmod -R 777 /var/stormtmp**

**sudo gedit apache-storm-0.9.2-incubating/conf/storm.yaml**

Edit the opened file such that it should have following properties set(JAVA_HOME path, you can use jdk7 or higher versions. Java must be installed in your system) :

storm.zookeeper.servers: - "localhost"

storm.zookeeper.port: 2181

nimbus.host: "localhost"

storm.local.dir: "/var/stormtmp"

java.library.path: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"

supervisor.slots.ports:

-6700

-6701

-6702

-6703

worker.childopts: "-Xmx768m"

nimbus.childopts: "-Xmx512m"

supervisor.childopts: "-Xmx256m"

If everything goes fine, you are now ready with apache-zookeeper-kafka-storm, you can restart the system, That's it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't have to install ZeroMQ and JZMQ from source.